# Kendo grid multi rows select with shift and arrow keys

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to select rows in Kendo grid with shift+up/down arrow keys. Sample code is as below. If I set selectable property to 'multiple row' the 'keydown' event is not firing. If I set it to just 'row' it fires.

To me 'mutiple row' is needed because I want this funcitonality when user uses shift/ctrl with mouse to select multiple rows. Along with this if user wants to use only keyboard how can I select multiple rows?

You can find sample code here also [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzm5dwvo/25/)

```
<div id="grid"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ],
  navigatable: true,
  selectable: 'multiple row',
});

var data = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
//console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
var arrows = [37, 38, 39, 40];
data.table.on("keydown", function (e) {
console.log(e.keyCode);
  //if (arrows.indexOf(e.keyCode) >= 0) {
  if (e.shiftKey && (arrows.indexOf(e.keyCode) >= 0)){
  console.log("shiftkey + arrow");
    setTimeout(function () {
      data.select($("#grid_active_cell").closest("tr"));
    },1);
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Strange, it works for me with *multiple rows*. I was able to select with shit+up/down. The console got the log "shiftkey  + arrow".

Comment: The sample I have shared working for you? Now also I tried the same sample. Not working for me.

Comment: It is working really fine. I'm using Chrome 51.0.2704.103. I can pick any individual item with ctrl+mouse, I can select an interval with shift+mouse and I can select one at time with shift+arrows. Just like windows explorer.

Comment: I am using this chrome version 51.0.2704.106 m. Still not working. This is strange. When I run the code in Edge or IE11 it is working fine.

Comment: This is wierd. I don't know what to say.